# How to allow all domains for Image nextjs config?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

I have various image url and changes over time (the image are taken for web by url address and not locally or from a private storage). In order to render `<Image />` tag , domains should be passed on to nextjs config.
It isn't possible to pass in 100s of url over time.

How to allow all domains ?

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  images: {
    domains: [
      "img.etimg.com",
      "assets.vogue.com",
      "m.media-amazon.com",
      "upload.wikimedia.org",
    ],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

I tried this but dint work,
`"*.com"`

Comment: An alternative is to use <img /> tag instead of Next JS <Image /> tag.

Comment: I'm currently using normal img tag,but I would like to use next's Image tag to get a better optimisation.

Comment: You might try using regex with Loader
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader

Answer (score 87):

It works for me, accordingly next.js documentation:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "**",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

[Next.js configuration options](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image#configuration-options)

Comment: `remotePatterns` exists [since v12.3.0](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/releases/tag/v12.3.0). It was [first introduced in v12.2.0](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12-2#remote-patterns-experimental) as an experimental feature.

Comment: Any idea why this could fail for `https://www.si.com`? It works for all other URLs but this one still throws.

Comment: Please tell me, I have updated next.js 12.3.4. and prescribe remotePatterns. But when building, I get into images (the "url" parameter is not allowed). Have you ever encountered such a thing ? I described the problem in more detail in the topics below: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/50028 ,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76181016/what-wrong-next-js-image-dont-work-on-server

Comment: Indeed it work for all except thing like : 

https://www...

https://www.thestreet.com/.image/ar_1.91%2Cc_fill%2Ccs_srgb%2Cfl_progressive%2Cg_xy_center%2Cq_auto:good%2Cw_1200%2Cx_2778%2Cy_1348/MTk3MDkxMTU2NzA4ODI4MjQz/usedcarbuyersleadjq20230407.jpg

Answer (score 17):

The Domain is required to be explicit per their documentation

> To protect your application from malicious users, you must define a list of image provider domains that you want to be served from the Next.js Image Optimization API.

You can also see that the source code allows for url's to be evaluated, a wildcard is not accepted.

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/client/image.tsx#L864

### Solve

You should look at a proxy like cloudinary or imgix and allow those domains in the `next.config` and use their  [fetch](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/fetch_remote_images) features to load external image.

i.e

With cloudinary as the allowed domain

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['res.cloudinary.com'],
  },
};
```

and then in your code

```
<Image
src="https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/fetch/https://a.travel-assets.com/mad-service/header/takeover/expedia_marquee_refresh.jpg"
width={500}
height={500}
/>
```

**Important**

The following StackBlitz utilizes their demo account to fetch an external image from Expedia.com, you should get your own account for production.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-pxrg99?file=pages%2Findex.js

Comment: See https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader-configuration, there is a dedicated option for loaders now.

Comment: Per my understanding, the question asks for all domains to be allowed - even with a custom `loader` you have to be explicit about the URL string.

Comment: Yeah and you suggested to whitelist the `res.cloudinary.com` domain and then use the `fetch` API. Instead you could just use the cloudinary loader. No need to prepend the cloudinary URL to the actual URL then.

Answer (score 5):

`images.domains` is **deprecated** in **NextJs 14**.

To refer next js new doc, you have to use like bellow code in `next.config.js` file.

```
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "www.your-website.com", // if your website has no www, drop it
      },
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "localhost",
      },
    ],
  },
};
module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Answer (score 1):

best and current way to do it is

```
images: {
   remotePatterns: [
   {
      protocol: "https",
      hostname: "**",
    },
   ],
},
```

all other methods are deprecated